# Why Spring Boot project is unable to find the ProductRepository extended from JPARepository interface for MySQL based CRUD Application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring Boot. I am trying to to implement a simple CRUD application in Spring Tool Suite using JPARepository and MySQL. I am receiving the below error when trying to run the project as Spring Boot App.

**Error**

```
Field repo in com.project.rest.ProductServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.project.repos.ProductRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.project.repos.ProductRepository' in your configuration.
```

Below is the project structure

[image]

Below is the project code and configurations.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.project.rest'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.26'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8000
server.servlet.context-path=/productcrud
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=theCORRECTPassword
```

**ProductCrudApplication.java**

```
package com.project.rest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@SpringBootApplication
public class ProductCrudApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductCrudApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Product.java**

```
package com.project.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;



@Entity
public class Product {
    
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int price;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    

}
```

**ProductRepository.java**

```
package com.project.repos;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.project.entities.Product;


@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {

}
```

**ProductServiceImpl.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.project.entities.Product;
import com.project.repos.ProductRepository;

@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl {
    
    @Autowired
    ProductRepository repo;

    
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return (List<Product>)repo.findAll();
    }

    
    public Product getProduct(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return repo.findById(id).get();
    }

    
    public String createProduct(Product product) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Product p=repo.save(product);
        if(p!=null) {
            return ("Product created with id "+p.getId());
        }
        return "Error creating";
    }

    
    public String updateProduct(Product product) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Product p=repo.save(product);
        if(p!=null) {
            return ("Product created with id "+p.getId());
        }
        return "Error updating";
    }
}
```

**ProductController.java**

```
package com.project.rest;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.project.entities.Product;

@RestController
public class ProductController {
    
    @Autowired
    ProductServiceImpl productService;
    
    @GetMapping("/products")
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return productService.getProducts();
    }

    @GetMapping("/product/{id}")
    public Product getProduct(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return productService.getProduct(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(productService.createProduct(product),HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping("/update")
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(productService.updateProduct(product),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    

}
```

Below are the attempts for fixing the issue.

**Attempt 1**

ProductCrudApplication.java

```
package com.project.rest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.project.repos") //added this
public class ProductCrudApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductCrudApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productService': Error creating bean with name 'productServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo': Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.project.repos.ProductRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on ProductCrudApplication: Not a managed type: class com.project.entities.Product
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:787) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1418) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:960) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:464) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1358) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at com.project.rest.ProductCrudApplication.main(ProductCrudApplication.java:14) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo': Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.project.repos.ProductRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on ProductCrudApplication: Not a managed type: class com.project.entities.Product
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:787) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1418) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.project.repos.ProductRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on ProductCrudApplication: Not a managed type: class com.project.entities.Product
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1773) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.project.entities.Product
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:135) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1820) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

**Attempt 2**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.project.repos") //added this
@ComponentScan({"com.project.entities","com.project.repos","com.project.rest"}) //added this
public class ProductCrudApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductCrudApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Error - same as in Attempt 1

**Attempt 3**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.project.entities","com.project.repos","com.project.rest"}) //added this
public class ProductCrudApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductCrudApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Error - same as original one "Field repo in com.project.rest.ProductServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.project.repos.ProductRepository' that could not be found."

I will request to kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Spring Boot automatically scans for entities placed in the same package or sub-packages as your main application class `(@SpringBootApplication)`.
No additional configuration is needed as long as your entity classes are annotated with `@Entity`.

Currently, your entity is in the package `com.project.entities`, and the main application class is in package `com.project.rest`. hence your entities are not getting scanned.

The simplest way to fix is to move your main class to package `com.project`

Alternatively, If you want to keep your entities located in a different package than your main application class, you can use the `@EntityScan` annotation.
Add `@EntityScan` to your main application class or a dedicated configuration class, specifying the base package(s) where your entities reside.

Comment: For sake of simplicity I put all the classes under 1 package and the code worked. Thank you. You mentioned , if I keep entity classes in a completely different package , I have to use @EntityScan on main application class. If someone keeps the Repository interface in a different package, what annotation should he use on main application class?

Comment: In that case, you can specify the package in the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation for repository classes

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `@Entity` annotation from the wrong package. You should use next:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
```

for the `Product.java` class.

Please refer to the annotation doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee%2F7%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/persistence/Entity.html

Comment: The original poster is using Spring Boot 3.2.1.  Spring Boot 3 migrated from Java EE to [Jakarta EE APIs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes#third-party-library-upgrades).  The `import jakarta.persistence.Entity;` is correct for Jakarta EE.